# Does the latest version of, the flutter plugin, url_launcher supports opening of desktop(windows, macOS) directory in native file explorer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

I checked its source code, for both macOs and windows, [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher) . Since, swift and c++ are not my strong languages but having a brief look at the code made me wonder if the support, for opening the directory in the native file explorer (of windows and macOs), when a local path of that directory is provided, is already available. Because I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) about it. Any alternate solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73317) for the answer to the above-mentioned question.